# Laravel foreach loop error message: Server Error in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I pull the data in json format, but I can't access the sub-elements in some way, it's not oddly worth it, it only takes the first character.

```
$log_example = $request->all();
$logs = json_encode($log_example);
$data = json_decode((string) $logs, true);
return $data['log_list'];
```

The returned data is as follows

```
{
   "0":["1","SALES","5,00","REMOVED"],
   "1":["2","SALES","10,00","REMOVED"],
   "2":["1","BUYER","2","DROPPED"]
}
```

When I output with the dd function, the data returns as follows

dd($log_example);

return as below

```
array:1 [ "log_lists" => "{"0":["1"," SALES","10,00","REMOVED"],"1":["1"," SALES","10,00","REMOVED"],"2":["1"," BUYER","10,00","DROPPED"]}" ]
```

Here I want to pull the first data for example

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
       echo $d[0];
    }
```

return only this charecters {

Comment: `echo "$v-"` ??

Comment: `$data['log_list']` or `$data['log_lists']`? Have you tried to print out `$d` in your first `foreach`?

Comment: @kerbh0lz yes Datas come

Comment: xNoJustice edited post

Comment: you dont have to $logs = json_encode($log_example);
$data = json_decode((string) $logs, true);, what is dd($log_example?)

Comment: @mrhn when I write dd function it return array:1 [
            "log_lists" => "{"0":["1"," SALES","10,00","REMOVED"],"1":["1"," SALES","10,00","REMOVED"],"2":["1"," BUYER","10,00","DROPPED"]}"
          ]

Comment: Looks as though the entries are JSON themselves, try replacing `echo $d[0];` with `print_r(json_decode($d,true));`

Comment: @NigelRen ok return as below Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => SALES [2] => 10,00 [3] => REMOVED ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => SALES [2] => 20,00 [3] => REMOVED ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry in the key value array is `JSON`, not the whole `log_example`, i would not decode it as you do, instead something like this.

```
$data = json_decode($log_example['log_lists'], true);
```

Now you should be able to loop as shown here.

```
foreach($data as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $value) {
        var_dump($value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why json_encode a JSON string ? you can only json_decode it.

Comment: @VincentDecaux $request->all(); functions return data array so firstly, it must json_encode

Comment: Yes but `$log_example['log_lists']` returns a string.

Comment: I updated my answer :) got lost in decode encode, i believe this will work

Comment: @mrhn ok comes value but how can show it for example, $value[0][0] etc..

Comment: var_dump($data[0][0])